# Multiple ThisWorkbook in excel VBA in user defined function

Tags: vba, excel

In excel I created the user defined function below. I tested it worked perfectly. Next time I open the excel file I get an "Automation error". I delete the reference from excel. I try to debug the udf by calling it with a procedure, at the first instruction

```
Set mySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("összesíto")
```

there is Automation error catastropic failure again.

The sheet name is correct; I seen an error message in watch window: Can't compile module; "object variable or with block variable is not set", after that my other UDF is not working either. The strange thing is this: function below works perfectly, but fail after I close the file and reopen it.

UPDATE: I realized another symptom. In the wrong file the MS excel object are multiplied somehow, there are much more sheets and more ThisWorkbook object. Only after I run the the udf, close the file and reopen it.

UPDATE: I opened the same file on another machine where a 32 bit excel is installed (yesterday I tried on an 64 bit excel). Here the udf works perfectly, there is no automation error, I do not see multiple version of ThisWorkbook object.

UPDATE: when i call once the udf from a single cell, and I debug the execution then a strange thing happen. The function is executed 3 times. The first 2 run gives a wrong result (the Value2 row gives back incorrect 0), the third one is correct. I know it does not makes sense.

```
Function SumHelperTableColumns(columnName As String) As Double
Dim myTable As Excel.ListObject
Dim mySheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim myRow As Excel.ListRow

Set mySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("összesíto")
Set myTable = mySheet.ListObjects("Számlák")
Dim tableName As String
Dim tableAndColumnName As String

result = 0

For Each myRow In myTable.ListRows
    tableName = Intersect(myRow.Range, myTable.ListColumns("Tábla név").Range)
    If tableName <> "" Then
        tableAndColumnName = "s_" & tableName & "[" & columnName & "]"
        actualValue = Range(tableAndColumnName).Value2
        result = result + actualValue
    End If
 Next myRow
SumHelperTableColumns = result
End Function

Sub TestSumHelperTableColumns()
    SumHelperTableColumns ("Havi jövedelem")
End Sub
```

Comment: Just a tip: try to avoid the use of special characters like `á` when defining sheet names as objects.

Comment: It seems ThisWorkbook is not available, no idea why.

Comment: Or maybe the worksheet `összesíto`? Open the macro explorer and instead of `Set mySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("összesíto")` try `Set mySheet = Sheet1`, where Sheet1 is the worksheet code name (the one you can check in the worksheet properties in the macro explorer) http://www.onlinepclearning.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/sheet-name-code-name.png

Comment: screenshot can make it easier to see what the problem is. Sounds like you have another workbook attached or linked. The default is `VBAProject.ThisWorkbook.` but the Code Names can be changed https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/2240/excel-vba-tips-and-tricks/11272/worksheet-name-index-or-codename#t=20161027211906753211